# How can i find unique record in python by row count?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

df:

```
  Country  state      item 
0 Germany  Augsburg   Car
1 Spain    Madrid     Bike
2 Italy    Milan      Steel
3 Paris    Lyon       Bike
4 Italy    Milan      Steel
5 Germany  Augsburg   Car
```

In the above dataframe, if we take unique record Appearance.

```
  Country  state      item  Appeared
0 Germany  Augsburg   Car     1
1 Spain    Madrid     Bike    1
2 Italy    Milan      Steel   1
3 Paris    Lyon       Bike    1
4 Italy    Milan      Steel   2
5 Germany  Augsburg   Car     2
```

Since row no. 4 and 5 appeared for the second time, i want to change their item name to differentiate both record.If a record is appeared more than once in the data, item name should be rename as Item_A for 1st appearance and Item_B for the second appearance...
Output:

```
Country  state      item  Appeared
0 Germany  Augsburg   Car_A   1
1 Spain    Madrid     Bike    1
2 Italy    Milan      Steel_A 1
3 Paris    Lyon       Bike    1
4 Italy    Milan      Stee_B  2
5 Germany  Augsburg   Car_B   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the `Appreared` column by `groupby().cumcount`, then add the suffixes:

```
# unique values
duplicates = df.duplicated(keep=False)

# Appearance count
df['Appeared'] = df.groupby([*df]).cumcount().add(1)

# add the suffixes
suffixes = np.array(list('ABC'))
df.loc[duplicates, 'item'] = df['item'] + '_' + suffixes[df.Appeared-1]
```

Output:

```
   Country     state     item  Appeared
0  Germany  Augsburg    Car_A         1
1    Spain    Madrid     Bike         1
2    Italy     Milan  Steel_A         1
3    Paris      Lyon     Bike         1
4    Italy     Milan  Steel_B         2
5  Germany  Augsburg    Car_B         2
```

Comment: You could also map the Appeared column with `{i: chr(i+64) for i in range(1, 26)}` :D